# select from two independent table based on not exist a row in a third table joining them

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, query-optimization

I have a problem regarding an SQL query.
I need all rows from two independent tables those do not have a row joining them in a third table. The query is working this way but it has a very bad performance.

*now my query look like this:*

```
SELECT s.id, 
       u.id 
FROM   table1 s, 
       table2 u 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       ( 
              SELECT * 
              FROM   table3 sj 
              WHERE  sj.s_id=s.id 
              AND    sj.u_id=u.id
       )
```

*Keys on table3 are:*

```
ALTER TABLE `table3`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ADD KEY `s_id` (`s_id`),
    ADD KEY `u_id` (`u_id`);
```

table1 has 4 rows,
table2 has 80.000 rows,
table3 has 30.000 rows

Any ideas how to optimise it?
Now the query takes up to 20 minutes to give results.

*Edit:*
Regarding the 20 minutes -> i forgot to set a key on the `table3(u_id)`
After setting the key it required just some seconds. Great.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks for downvote, but i think my question and even my SQL query are very clear to everyone who ever had contact with SQL. What more i should provide a CREATE TABLE code for three tables with IDs only?

Comment: Note that 'EXITS' is not a recognised term in MySQL

Comment: In addition, as well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems to me like the right way to do what you want. I would just rewrite the old-school implicit join to an explicit `cross join` (but that’s semantically équivalent).

For performance, you need an index on `table3(s_id, u_id)`.

However, you need to keep in mind that cross joining the tables generates a derived tables of about 2.4 billions rows, so there is still lot of work to do for the database in the `not exists` condition.

If `sid` and `uid` are not unique in the source table, then you can deduplicate before cross joining:

```
select ...
from (select distinct id from table1) s
cross join (select distinct id from table3) u 
where not exists (...)
```

Comment: if sid and uid are not unique -> you mean it there are rows in table3 which has several time the same sid and uid -> no its a progress table so there is just existing one row each combination.

Comment: regarding the index -> each column an index or a multiple column index? i am just reading there are multiple column indexes, till now for me this was a blurred topic

Comment: @ChrisMaster: yes I mean a multi column index on table3. By not unique, I meant unique in source tables (table1 and table2).

Comment: Ok i understand, In sourcetable its auto_increment/unique/primary. Great. Thank you.

Comment: After change from two single indexes to a multi column index the request time decreased to half the time.